# Scrolling in the wrong position 360 product Slider

Tags: javascript, css

On scroll the slider is sliding in the wrong direction. Have you got any idea how can I fix this? I am using plugin for this "treesixteen slider"

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = init;

var product;
function init(){

    product1 = $('.product1').ThreeSixty({
        totalFrames: 97, // Total no. of image you have for 360 slider
        endFrame: 97, // end frame for the auto spin animation
        currentFrame: 1, // This the start frame for auto spin
        imgList: '.threesixty_images', // selector for image list
        progress: '.spinner', // selector to show the loading progress
         imagePath:'assets/product1/', // path of the image assets
        filePrefix: 'a', // file prefix if any
        ext: '.jpg', // extention for the assets
        height: 265,
        width: 400,
        navigation: true,
        disableSpin: true, // Default false
        responsive: true,
        playSpeed: 10,
    });

}
</script>
```

This is the WebSitite: http://pappu-lighting.com/Series/Kutiq/LAST.html
Second sextion with the 360 degree slider.

Comment: I think renaming resources in reverse order will help you: a1.png should become a97.png, a2.png - a96.png etc.

Comment: That was Genius :D thank you!

Comment: I have one more issue. Do you have any idea how to speed up the slider?

Comment: That could be very obvious, but I'd propose you to change the value of the "playSpeed" property in the ThreeSixty config object.

Comment: its not obvious at all, because the "playSpeed" is about autoplay, not about moving with the mouse I needed to add "speedMultiplier" property to fix it. Thank you again for the previous issue.